# How does the evaluation process example of jBPM works?

Tags: jbpm

I tried the evaluation process of jBPM suite, and this is just what I need, but course to apply in a project that I want to start.

I have readed the jBPM documentation and I executed successfuly the evaluation example that comes with the jbpm-installer full version (of jbpm 5.3.0), but it is not clear for me the next points. I will try to describe in this example. Let's say I have to create a litle web sistem from scratch, users of this web system will login and they will start processes instances and can check if they have tasks assigned (yes,just like the evaluation example, but of course, they do not use the jbpm-console to see that information, The system must have its very own presentation on web ) and also they can perform those task, so the process can continue.

So I create a process definition with drools-guvnor tool, I compiled the process, now it appears in jbpm-console overs processes definitions,I even can start this process in the console (please, letme know if I'm those are not the right steps to create a process), at this point:

-How do I create/generate the forms to allow users to complete the tasks?. Just like evaluation process does.

-Is it possible to use that forms outside the jbpm-console?, so I can put them into my web system and the users use them.

-Could I use the server:8080/gwt-console-server REST API to start processes, get processes information and manage them instead of programaticaly?or I will always need to (for example) start my processes by using the `ksession.startProcess("com.myprocess");`

and finally, as I'm not to much involved with java technologies to create web pages, applications.
-In order to create a WEB system that uses jBPM to manage the bussiness logic, shows its own presentation on web to users, let  them perform human tasks (fill forms, start processes) and store the data, what achitechture do you recommend?

Thanks very much in advanced

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I'm reviewing the links you posted.

Answer (score 2):

> -How do I create/generate the forms to allow users to complete the tasks?. Just like evaluation process does.

Forms are simple html templates.  You can:
 - use the tooling to generate the forms for you:
http://docs.jboss.org/jbpm/v5.3/userguide/ch.designer.html#d0e4369
http://kverlaen.blogspot.it/2012/03/reward-system-demo.html
 - create the forms yourself in the web designer (select the task and click on the human task icon to edit the html)

> -Is it possible to use that forms outside the jbpm-console?, so I can put them into my web system and the users use them.

Yes, you could use the jBPM REST API to show the form in some frame.

> -Could I use the server:8080/gwt-console-server REST API to start processes, get processes information and manage them instead of programaticaly?or I will always need to (for example) start my processes by using the ksession.startProcess("com.myprocess");

Absolutely, if the REST API is providing all the features you need, you can just use it to start processes, get your task list, etc.  You can also instantiate a session embedded as part of your application but this is not a requirement.